# JQuery checkbox filter parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have list of checkboxes for genre filters. Here is HTML

```
<div class="gl-title">Türler</div>
<ul class="check-list filters" id="genres">
  <?php foreach($genres as $genre){?>
    <li>
      <div class="customCheck">
        <input type="checkbox" data-genrename="<?php echo $genre->slug; ?>" id="tur_<?php echo $genre->term_id;?>">
        <label for="tur_<?php echo $genre->term_id;?>"></label>
      </div>
      <div class="cl-text">
        <?php echo $genre->name;?>
      </div>
    </li>
    <?php }?>
</ul>
</div>
```

On checkbox click i want to add genrename at the end of the url.Here is my JQuery code

```
$(".customCheck").children("input").unbind(click).click(function(){
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $(this).prop("checked", false);
    } else {
        $(this).prop("checked", true);
    }
    alert("blabla");
    var curUrl = window.location.href;
    alert(curUrl);

    if(curUrl.substring("?tur=")>-1){
        window.location=curUrl+"+"+$(this).attr("data-genrename");
    }else{
        window.location=curUrl+"?tur="+$(this).attr("data-genrename");
    }
});
```

"tur" means genre in my language.(For you can understand url.)
This function is under document ready.Checking functions are working but i can't see alert box on click. I tried with incognito mode for caches nothing changed. What is problem Thanks so much

Comment: And you're not getting any errors, like `click is not defined`, from the line `unbind(click)` where you're missing the quotes.

Comment: Oh sometimes answer is simple like that. I didn't know i have to use quotes for events. Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Is there some reason you are unbinding before binding here?  Seems odd that.

Comment: If i don't do that click event double firing and checkbox value not changing. I dont know why.

Comment: AH my bad I should have noted the loop on the class.  Adjusted my answer based on that to fix that also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be much simpler, fix some syntax issues and an issue with substring being misused and should use `str.indexOf(searchValue[, fromIndex])` instead.

Note I used `.data` not `.attr` as the better method here.  `!$(this).is(":checked")` can also be `!$(this)[0]checked` or even `!this.checked`

**EDIT**: Adjust for binding issue by removal of class

```
$('#genres').on("change", "input[type='checkbox']", function() {
  // set checkbox to what it is NOT (checked or unchecked (not sure why)
  $(this).prop("checked", !$(this).is(":checked"));
  alert("blabla");
  var curUrl = window.location.href;
  alert(curUrl);
  var turp = "?tur=";
  if (curUrl.indexOf(turp) > -1) {
    window.location = curUrl + "+" + $(this).data("genrename");
  } else {
    window.location = curUrl + turp + $(this).data("genrename");
  }
});
```

Note that you could also do: (but which is better is debatable)

```
var curUrl =  (window.location.href.indexOf(turp) > -1) window.location.href + '+': window.location.href+"?tur=";
window.location = curUrl + $(this).data("genrename");
```

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you want to play with check-box, kindly always use .change() event instead of .click().

You can make check-box checked or unchecked using Ctrl + SpaceBar key at that time .click() event will not be fired.

```
 $(document).on("change", ".customCheck :checkbox", function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $(this).prop("checked", false);
    }
    else {
        $(this).prop("checked", true);
    }
    alert("blabla");
    var curUrl = window.location.href;
    alert(curUrl);

    if (curUrl.substring("?tur=") > -1) {
        window.location = curUrl + "+" + $(this).attr("data-genrename");
    }
    else {
        window.location = curUrl + "?tur=" + $(this).attr("data-genrename");

    }

});
```

Comment: Thanks so much i will accept this as answer in 7 minutes :)

Comment: Yeah working but i have a problem the if condination not working it is always add "?tur=" to like this "site.com/?tur=a?tur=b" instead of "?tur=a+b"

Comment: I would probably bind this to the `genres` using `#genres` as the selector instead of document here.

Comment: Will it any effect to url ? That seems simple to me if i bind to genres it will behind 2 elements this way only 1 element.